# Compile 32 bit VS 2003 project to 64 bit

Tags: c++, 64-bit, visual-studio-2003, managed-extensions

I currently have a 32 bit dll that was created with Visual Studio 2003 in C++ using [Managed Extensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Managed_Extensions_for_C%2B%2B). I'm now trying to compile a 64 bit version without having to upgrade to C++/CLI. I've been following the tutorial at [this location](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/forumarchives/vclanguage/Aug2005/post23130822.asp). I'm getting the following error:

> fatal error C1197:
>   cannot reference
>   'c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v1.1.4322\mscorlib.dll'
>   as the progam has already referenced
>   'c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.dll'

I can't figure out what is referencing the .NET 2.0 version of the dll.

Comment: 64 bits with VS2003? VS2003 didn't come with a 64 bits cross compiler?!?

Comment: Indeed. Apparently, you can download the Platform SDK (which contains a 64 bit compiler) and compile it within VS2003 (provided you start it with the right environment variables).

Answer (score 1):

Do you manually call the .dll file in the code? Like in this?

```
#using "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322\mscorlib.dll
```

If so, you can change this line to just:

```
#using "mscorlib.dll"
```

Comment: It happens regardless whether I specify the full path, '#using "mscorlib.dll"', '#using <mscorlib.dll>' or omit completely.

Answer (score 0):

Are you including a library that links to a different version of mscorlib?

Are you specifying both the /clr option and doing a #using "mscorlib.dll" ?